# Godot - How to set up a modular character with collision being defined in the child nodes?

Tags: godot

I am triying to build "modular" ships in my 2d game, meaning a ship has a hull, an engine, cannons, etc. each being an own scene.
A ship could be set up like this

```
Ship   
|- Hull  
  |- Sprite   
  |- CollisionShape
|- Engine  
  |- Sprite   
  |- CollisionShape
  |- ParticleSystem
```

Now I am stuck with the following problem. I set up the Ship node as KinematicBody2D as I use that node for movement.
BUT the collision should come from the sub scenes (Hull, Engine, etc.).
So I made them KinematicBodies too and added the CollisionShapes.

However this does not work, as the Ship needs a CollisionShape child (KinematicBody2D) and it being in the nested Scenes (Hull, Engine, etc.) does not suffice. In addition if I move the Ship node with move_and_collide/_slide the child nodes do not collide.

I do not think that my current approach is correct.
What can I do to accomplish this without breaking my modularity by moving the children CollisionShapes to the Ship?

Comment: `KinematicBody2D` needs its own collision shape anyway. Could you please clarify, what does "modular" mean for your ships. Is it like the international space station or something else? Do all modules always travel together or they can split apart and move independently?

Comment: With modular I mean that the ship consists of different parts, for example a cockpit, a cargo hold, an engine, etc. The modules should move together as one entity.

What I tried and had some success with, was giving each part/module the correct collision shape and reparenting these on load. But this does not really feal right...

Answer (score 1):

As a `PhysicsBody2D`, `KinematicBody2D` needs collision shape if you want it to collide with other physics bodies. So you could add a shape to the `Ship` node that will fit the entire ship or be slightly smaller than it.

Of course, there is more than one solution. A possible way suggests that you could make ship elements (engine, hull, cannons, etc) be the `Area2D` nodes. Using Area2D signals and `_on_Area2D_area_entered(area)` method you could code the unique response of events, like a collision with an enemy bullet, for each type of ship module.

```
Ship (KinematicBody2D)   
|
|__CollisionShape2D
|
|__Hull (Area2D)
|  |_Sprite   
|  |_CollisionShape2D
|
|__Engine (Area2D)  
   |_Sprite   
   |_CollisionShape2D
   |_ParticleSystem
```

Comment: And if I want to dynamically change parts of the ship, for example the engine, I would have to re-compute the parents CollisionShape2D?

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, I had the same question until yesterday and found a solution, so here it is for anyone who still have this issue creating modular scenes:

In the Ship Kinematicbody create one CollisionShape for every ship module (you can add it through code if you wish) and through coding make each of the CollisionShapes you created for each module get the extents transforms (collisionshape.shape.extents.transform) from the CollisionShape present in the respectives module scenes (you will just use them to get the shapes you set, no need for the modules to be physics body as you only need the data from the collision extents).